# I have a problem with es_extended when i try to buy ammo and it did not save after restart

Tags: lua, fivem

So whenever i buy ammo in shop for pistol for example, when i rejoin it just reset the ammo back

I tried downloading different script for weapon shop but it didnt work at all

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so maybe its not from es_extended, i dont know where it came from this problem, no console errors nothing,

Comment: i use custom made weapon shop

Comment: ooo think i find the problem, im using vMenu and there says that you need to save your loadout. Can i disable this option so whenever someone buys a weapon it just save your loadout